# How can I locally save images and batch upload them using another PHP function?

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a simple website where a user can upload multiple images and afterward click on a button to batch upload them to an AWS S3 bucket using PHP. Therefore the images need to be stored locally but also be accessible by PHP. So far I've learned that cookies are too small to store images and that the localstorage is not accessible using PHP.

This I what I've done so far:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1 class="title" id="pages_count"></h1>
            <div id="images" class="images"></div>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li id="add_img_li">
            <form runat="server">
                <label class="custom-file-upload" id="add_img_btn">Add image
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp" accept="image/*">
                </label>
            </form>
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <button class="custom-file-upload" id="uploadbtn" type="submit" onclick="btnChange()">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

    // hide uploadbtn until image is uploaded
    document.getElementById("uploadbtn").style.visibility = "hidden";

    function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }

    // function for converting images to base64
    function getDataUrl(img) {
        // Create canvas
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Set width and height
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        // Draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    }

    // live image preview
    var uploaded_img_count = 0;
    var current_img = 0;
    var imgs_left = 5;

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            if (uploaded_img_count < 5) {
                // create image
                console.log("image: " + uploaded_img_count.toString());
                var image = document.createElement("li"); // Create a <button> element
                image.innerHTML = '<img id="preview_' + uploaded_img_count.toString() +
                    '" src="#" alt="Scan" width="100" height="100" draggable="false" class="preview_img" style="visibility: visible;"/><br>'; // hidden
                document.getElementById("images").appendChild(image); // Append <button> to <body>

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    console.log("imageaaf<sdf: " + current_img.toString());
                    document.getElementById('preview_' + current_img.toString()).src = e.target.result
                    current_img++;
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string

                // save image to cookie for batch upload
                const img = document.querySelector("#preview_" + uploaded_img_count.toString());
                img.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                    const dataUrl = getDataUrl(event.currentTarget);
                    document.cookie = "img_" + uploaded_img_count.toString() + "=" + dataUrl +
                        ";expires=Fri, 7 Jan 2022 12:00:00 UTC;path=/";
                    console.log(document.cookie);
                });

                uploaded_img_count++;
                imgs_left--;

                // update pages count label & remove add button if maximum image number is reached
                if (uploaded_img_count >= 5) {
                    document.getElementById('add_img_li').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('add_img_li'));
                }
                document.getElementById('pages_count').innerText = uploaded_img_count.toString() +
                    " / 5 pages uploaded";

                // unhide findtasks button
                document.getElementById("uploadbtn").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

The issue here is that when I try to log the cookies, it just says: `img_1=data:image/jpeg;` instead of showing me the base64 string. I'd like to save the images on the phone before uploading them for performance reasons. Previously I had to wait about 10 seconds after taking an image until I could capture another one. Are there any other ways to do this without cookies or localstorage?

Comment: Why not write some code for that? Have you tried anything that is not working yet?

Comment: _“where a user can upload multiple images and afterward […]”_ - if they already _have_ uploaded the images, then they _are_ available to PHP already, no? _“that the localstorage is not accessible using PHP”_ - JS can access localstorage, JS can make a request to send data to the server … (But then you would be uploading the same data a second time, if you really meant what you said, that the images already _had_ been uploaded prior to this step.)

Comment: Would [Uploading multiple files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) help? Not clear if the upload to your server or to AWS is a problem

Comment: I'd say you should store uploaded files on your server first, then after upload to AWS you can remove them. Local storing can be tricky.

Comment: Either upload direct to aws using JavaScript, without bothering your server at all. Or store the images on your server prior to the batch upload. If the images are already uploaded then they'd already be on your server and accessible to PHP. If they're not then it's really not clear what you're talking about when you say `a user can upload multiple images `

Comment: The issue with uploading directly is that theoretically, any user could upload anything to my bucket, so I'd like to have my server in between, or do you know of any secure methods?

Comment: Do what I and someone else already said then. You just let the browser upload the images to your server. Then you can use PHP to upload them from the server to aws without revealing any credentials etc on the client side. Once that's done, you can delete them from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images on a user's local machine are never accessible to php as it runs on the server. You should look into creating an upload functionality using either HTML forms or JavaScript.

Comment: What I now decided to do is to save all the base64 hashes in invisible labels inside a form, whose contents can then be accessed by PHP using $_POST.

Comment: What exactly speaks against using `<input type="file" name="file" />` inside a `<form action="your-php.php" method="post"></form>`